# C# Object Initializer : Set Property from another one

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I have the following object where in my constructor I add a new Guid as the Id.

```
public class MyObject
{
  public MyObject()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }

  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String Test { get; set; }

}
```

I want to do something like that in an object initializer :

```
var obj = new MyObject
{
  Test = Id; // Get new GUID created in constructor
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You'd have to just set it in a separate statement:

```
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.Test = obj.Id;
```

The right-hand side of the property in an object initializer is just a normal expression, with no inherent connection to the object being initialized.

If this is something you regularly want to do with one specific type, you could add a method:

```
public MyObject CopyIdToTest()
{
    this.Test = Id;
    return this;
}
```

and then use:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject().CopyIdToTest();
```

or with other properties:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject 
{
    // Set other properties here
}.CopyIdToTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

No -- you can't access an object's properties inside an initializer. The initializer is basically some syntactic sugar for programmers.

Consider situations like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
     var Id = "hello";
    var obj = new MyObject
        {
            Test = Id // Get new GUID created in constructor
        };
    }
}
```

The `Id` you'd assign (if your idea was valid, which again, it isn't) isn't necessarily the `Id` you'd be getting.

Comment: Note that the constructor *has* completed before the "property setting" part of the initializer executes.

Comment: Yes -- I was conflating the initialization with construction. I'll edit for clarity, thanks.